# Android app using camera with android:screenOrientation="landscape"

Tags: android, camera, orientation

My app is screen_orientation_portrait,but when I opened camera,the picture in my camera is 90degreed rotated.
So I tried to add "android:screenOrientation="landscape",in demo ,it is ok,but when I use it in my app,the camera activity opened and  the app turned to be screen_orientation_landscaped,and the camera activity closed.
I reallied it is because when change the screen_orientation,the activity is going to reopen it self,but in my app,it dose not open after closed.What I can see is my ActivityGroup.
So can I just made my camera activity not reopen after the orientation is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to your activity in manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
```